# Как отправить GET запрос Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня на сайте есть форма отправки трек-номера для того, чтобы человек мог увидеть статус посылки, но у меня не получается её сделать

**html**

```
<form action="track/" method="post">
            <input type="track" name="track" class="form-control" id="track" aria-describedby="track">
            <button type="submit" class="ups-cta ups-cta_primary" style="cursor: pointer;">Track</button>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def tracking(request, track):
    if request.method == "POST":
        track = request.POST.get('track')
        return HttpResponse(track)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
from . import views

app_name='tracking'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name='main'),
    path('track/', views.tracking, name="tracking")
]
```

Comment: описание вопроса в заголовке не соответствует с описанием. Вам нужен `GET` или `POST`? Скорее всего пост. Но тогда вопрос что у вас не получается? Есть ошибки ? привидите их сюда в вопрос

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin
Мне нужен get-запрос, чтобы при отправке формы у меня бралось введённое значение в tracking(views), но этого не происходит, форма отправляется неизвестно куда, но до вьюшки не доходит
(я изменил на get-запрос, но всё равно не работает)

Comment: Во-первых если вы хотите отправить данные на сервер вам нужен `POST` запрос.  Во-вторых при отправке пост запроса у вас должна быть ошибка `csrf`.

Answer (score 0):

Такой POST запрос будет отклонен политикой обработкой CSFR. Ваш вопрос звучит: Как отправить **GET запрос**, но вы отправляете **POST**.

В текущих условиях вам достаточно заменить `<form action="track/" method="post">` -> `<form action="track/" method="get">`

и во view ловить его через `request.GET.get('track')`